# How to add and remove the pop-up text based on the condition by using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet-plugins

I want to show and hide the popup text based on the condition given below.

**.component.ts**

```
 var insidecirclespace1 = (lat, long) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.sensors.length; i++) {

        if (this.getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude, lat, long) <= 5) {
            circlemark[i].setStyle({
                color: 'red',
                weight: 1,
                opacity: 7.0
            });

            if (existfalg == 0) {
                this.wifiDrones.push({
                    "frequency": "",
                });
            }
        }
    }

    if (latlngs[latlngidx1] != undefined && latlngs02[latlngidx2] != undefined && latlngs03[latlngidx3] != undefined && latlngs04[latlngidx4] != undefined) {
        outsidespace(latlngs[latlngidx1].lat, latlngs[latlngidx1].lon, latlngs02[latlngidx2].lat, latlngs02[latlngidx2].lon, latlngs03[latlngidx3].lat, latlngs03[latlngidx3].lon, latlngs04[latlngidx4].lat, latlngs04[latlngidx4].lon);
    }
}
```

Now I want to show the pop-up text when the condition is `insidecirclespace1`and remove the popup in `outsidespace`.

I am new to this leaflet map, can anyone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

To add a popup to the layer call `circlemark[i].bindPopup('Custom popup text').openPopup();`

If you want to remove it call `layer.unbindPopup()`

Comment: Thanks @Falke Design, but at layer showing the error as cannot find name 'layer'

Comment: you need to replace `layer` with the layer which is outside, you have not shared the code with us ...